# Python sorting a list of pairs

Tags: python, list

Here is the list:

```
list = [[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [4, 2], [5, 2], [6, 5], [7, 6], [8,0]]
```

Think of each one of the two values in the pair as item#, and parent [item#, parent]. Parent referring to the item# as parent.

When sorted the list should look like this:

```
list = [[1, 0], [2, 0], [4, 2], [5, 2], [3, 0], [6, 5], [7, 6], [8, 0]]
```

As you see, each item with a parent that's not 0, is put behind the pair with the corresponding item# (parent == item#). If there are two or more numbers with the same parent, the number with the lower item# goes first.

I am trying to implement this in the most elegant way possible, but it's surprisingly tricky.
Any ideas?

Comment: why 3,0 and 8,0 went last

Comment: I don't understand why there are [3, 0], [8,0] at the very end, and [1, 0], [2, 0] at the very beginning.  The middle part makes sense though.

Comment: I wrote: "each item with a parent that's not 0". Meaning items with a 0 have no parents. That's the whole point.

Comment: I think your example is wrong, `[[1, 0], [2, 0], [4, 2], [5, 2], [3, 0], [6, 5], [7, 6], [8, 0]]` probably should be the answer.

Comment: You're right, I'll change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method to do what you are trying to achieve.

```
unsorted = [[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [4, 2], [5, 2], [6, 5], [7, 6], [8,0]]
sortList = []
sortDict = {}

for x in unsorted:
    if x[1] != 0:
        if x[1] in sortDict:
            sortDict[x[1]].append(x[0])
        else:
            sortDict[x[1]] = [x[0]]

for x in unsorted:
    if x[1] == 0:
        sortList.append(x)
    if x[0] in sortDict:
        sortList.extend([[y, x[0]] for y in sortDict[x[0]]])

print(sortList)
```

Result:

```
[[1, 0], [2, 0], [4, 2], [5, 2], [3, 0], [6, 5], [7, 6], [8, 0]]
```

I'll keep trying to get it smaller (and better), but this may be the only way to do what you are asking.
I assume that the starting list is sorted by `x[0]` as in your example.